# angular ui-grid highlight entire row by cell click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

It looks like a simple task, but I already spent 4 hours to find a solution. How can I highlight the entire row by cell click?

On register api I have next

```
 $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
       $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
       gridApi.cellNav.on.navigate($scope,function(selected){

          if('.ui-grid-cell-focus '){
            console.log("fired class")
                $(selected.row.entity).addClass('ui-grid-cell-focus')
                        }

            console.log("fired cell")
                        $(selected.row.entity).addClass('ui-grid-cell-focus')

            });
    };
```

I see how click on cell is fired, but I cannot force to color the row and I don't want to select the row, because I use check box selection for this purpose, I just want to highlight the row by click on any cell in this row. Could somebody tell me where my mistake is?

Attached [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/bWwGcEMgCRCA6wm6Zt2O?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish what you want is to add a cellClass definition to your columnDefs. That function takes two params: grid and row.

```
 $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [{
    name: 'id',
    width: '150',
    cellTemplate: "",
    cellClass: getCellClass
  }, {
    name: 'name',
    width: '200',
    cellClass: getCellClass
  } ...
];

 function getCellClass(grid, row) {
    return row.uid === selectedRow ? 'highlight' : '';
 }
```

On click you could set a variable to the uid of the row, and inside the cellClass function you can check if the uid of the current row matches the uid of the selected, if so, you can set the class to a class that properly reflects the background color of the selected row.

```
 var selectedRow = null;
 gridApi.cellNav.on.navigate($scope, function(selected) {
   if ('.ui-grid-cell-focus ') {
        selectedRow = selected.row.uid;
        gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);
   }
});
```

Here's a link to your updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/AgpAI2cmdqgNsSLVNjYA?p=preview

If you don't like the cellClass approach you could define custom cellTemplates and similarly react to a property you set on the row entity.

Comment: The only one thing which I still can't understand how it works is `gridApi.core.notifyDataChange`. Thank you a lot for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: gridApi.core.notifyDataChange is necessary to let ui-grid know to re-render the view. If you don't include that call it won't re-render and then it wouldn't reflect the desired css class. glad it helped!

Comment: What is the if ('.ui-grid-cell-focus ') for? Wouldn't it always evaluate to true?